# "Was für ein" als Interrogativartikel im Plural Genitiv

Tags: article, declension

Kann mir jemand sagen, ob "Was für ein" als Interrogativartikel im Plural Genitiv dekliniert wird oder nicht, weil es auf der Seite [deutschplus.net](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/98) dekliniert wird, nicht aber auf der Seite [Canoonet.eu](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-was_fuer.html#Anchor-Formen-35882).

Comment: Ich glaube, dass man einfach *was fur* benutzt: Was für Ereignisse gedenkt man an diesem Tag?

Comment: Ich würde ja lieber "Welcher?" in deinen Sätzen sehen. Was natürlich die Frage nicht beantworten würde ;)

Comment: Ich verstehe das Problem nicht. Canoonet sagt (zutreffend): *Die Genitivformen kommen nicht oder nur äußerst selten vor.* Solltest du dich also in der Situation finden, _was für ein_ im Genitiv verwenden zu wollen, solltest du die Konstruktion noch einmal überdenken.

Comment: @tofro: _Was für ein?_ und _Welcher?_ haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. _Was für ein Mensch war er?_ kannst du z.B. nicht umformulieren in _Welcher Mensch war er?_.

Comment: @chirlu: Yep. Meint nicht genau dasselbe. Im Beispiel mit den Ereignissen wäre ich  mit der (leicht) abweichenden Bedeutung allerdings zugunsten der Verständlichkeit zufrieden gewesen.

Comment: @boaten schon, vielleicht, ber ich würde dort Dativ setzen, "was für Ereignissen, welchen Ereignissen, welchem Ereignis"; Dem schadet nicht, dass "gedenken" im südlichen Raum den Genitiv regiert, wie auch bei "wegen" (ein Thema für sich). Kommt also ganz drauf an.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ehrlich gesagt kriege ich es gerade im Singular schon kaum hin, mir einen Satz mit *was für eines* auszudenken, der nicht ganz furchtbar geschwollen klingt. Im Plural ist das noch dreimal schlimmer. Ich weiß nicht, ob ich in meinem Leben überhaupt auch nur einmal *was für* im Plural mit Genitiv verwendet habe.

Im Singular ist die Sache natürlich relativ klar:

> **Was für eines** Vergehens wird er bezichtigt?

Im Plural wäre das wohl

> **Was für** Vergehen wird er bezichtigt?

Demnach gäbe es die Genitivform. Wie schon gesagt, klingt es aber ziemlich sperrig. Ich würde eher sagen

> **Welcher** Vergehen wird er bezichtigt?

Comment: Bevendorff, danke! ;)

Comment: Ich würde tatsächlich konstruieren, doch wohl nicht sagen, "Für was für ein Vergehen wird er ..." und schlussfolgern, dass "bezichtigen des ..." dort nicht passt. Denn ich würde "das vergehen des X" denken und immer auf "bezichtigt des X" reduzieren. Wie sollte man bitte "Ladendiebstahl" oder "Steuerhinterziehung" in einem ganzen Satz auf die Frage antworten? Ein Bsl. würde die Antwort sicher komplettieren.